# 433MHz RF run away TX burst with ATTiny85 IC

Tags: communication, attiny, rf, attiny85

I have recently created a sketch for an ATTiny85.

My project consists of:

- 1x ATTiny85 IC only
- 1x 433MHz RF module => using data pin `2`
- 2x input digital pins => using pin `3` and pin `4`

Running at 16MHz using the ATTiny85 board core from https://github.com/damellis/attiny

All running on a 5v 1A 7805 only using `24.4mA` idle `29.5mA` when TXing.

I have optimized my code a bit and the sketch works as intended.
However sometimes the RF 433 module just keeps sending data for a few seconds instead of sending a burst then waiting for my 7 second timeout.

I do use the internal pullup resistors on pin 3 and 4.

This happens intermittently.. I would like to know if anyone has had a similar problem and knows how to prevent this "*runaway transmission*".. Or suggestions code improvements etc.

Strangely enough I can get 450m+- line of sight (farm land) distance accurate pings on my sensitive receiver using this cheap module.

**RF 433 Module**

I have the one with the SMD coil I have also soldered a 17.3cm LAN wire as antenna.

[image]

**SDR Waterfall**

I expect a constant burst every 7s.

[image]

**Code**

The code starts by looping a switch statement over states when an input is H/L or a timer runs out a state is changed.

When a trigger state is initiated a for loop copies and concatinates a condenses hex string then the next for loop sends these signals over pin 2.

After the signal is sent the state then changes to a timeout to wait before sending a pulse again.

*This is where the problem is.*

Sometimes the signal keeps sending as if the state is stuck for a few seconds but then the timer starts working as expected...

The longer 15min timer works fine, it's only the 7s and 9s loops that seem to have this issue.

---

**Pictures of testing PCB**

[image]

[image]

---

**Full sketch**
[*updated with suggestions*]

```arduino
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define DATA_PIN PB2// digital pin 2
#define ALARM_TRIGGER_PIN PB3// digital pin 3
#define LEARN_PIN PB4// digital pin 4

//15min= 900000 ms
//16min = 960000 ms
//20min= 500000 ms
const unsigned long DELAY_TIME_ZONE_HEARTBEAT = 900000;//15min
const unsigned long DELAY_TIME_CHECKALARM_TIMEOUT = 7000;//7sec
const unsigned long DELAY_TIME_CHECKLEARN_TIMEOUT = 9000;//9sec

unsigned long Delay_Start_Check_Alarm = 0;
unsigned long Delay_Start_Heartbeat = 0;
unsigned long Delay_Start_Learn = 0;

char LEARN[] ="269369a6924d36da6c800";//condensed hexadecimal signal; learnState/tamper same signal
char ALARM[] = "da4da69a4934db69b200";//condensed hexadecimal signal
char HEARTBEAT[] ="1269b4d349269b6d36400";//condensed hexadecimal signal
uint16_t pulse = 1100;//Attiny85 chip needs more of delay time
uint8_t i;

//custom states
enum State 
{
  ALARMTIMEOUT,
  CHECKING,
  HEARTBEATTIMEOUT,
  HEARTBEATSEND,
  LEARNTIMEOUT,
  LEARNSEND,
  ALARMSEND
};

enum State state;

void setup() 
{    
  DDRB |= (1 << DATA_PIN);//replaces pinMode(DATA_PIN, OUTPUT);
  DDRB &= ~(1 << ALARM_TRIGGER_PIN); //replaces pinMode(ALARM_TRIGGER_PIN, INPUT);
  DDRB &= ~(1 << LEARN_PIN); //replaces pinMode(LEARN_PIN, INPUT);

  PORTB |= (1 << ALARM_TRIGGER_PIN);//initiate alarm pin pullup
  PORTB |= (1 << LEARN_PIN);//initiate learn pin pullup

  ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN); //Disable ADC, saves ~230uA

  Delay_Start_Check_Alarm = Delay_Start_Heartbeat = Delay_Start_Learn  = millis();//set to start millis
  state = CHECKING;//initial state
}

void Check_Alarm_And_Heartbeat() 
{
  unsigned long Mill = millis();//set to current time

  uint8_t alarmState = PINB&8;//read alarm pin 3
  uint8_t learnState = PINB&16;//read learn pin 4

  //main switch loop
    switch (state) 
    {
    case CHECKING:
         //constant checking here
         if((alarmState) && (!learnState))
          {
           state = ALARMSEND;//set state
           Delay_Start_Check_Alarm = Mill;//keep time
          }
         //learn loop
         if((learnState) && (!alarmState))
         {
           state = LEARNSEND;//set state
           Delay_Start_Learn = Mill;//keep time
         }
         //continue heartbeat
         if((!alarmState) && (!learnState))
         {
           state = HEARTBEATTIMEOUT;//set state
         }
         //if both are high prioratize learnState/tamper signal
         if((alarmState) && (learnState))
         {
           state = LEARNSEND;//set state; learnState/tamper same signal
           Delay_Start_Learn = Mill;//keep time
         }
        break;
    case LEARNSEND:
         {
           state = LEARNTIMEOUT;//set state
           char LEARNFINAL[168];//make LEARNFINAL var and define length
           strcpy(LEARNFINAL, LEARN);//copy LEARN to new LEARNFINAL var
           for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
           {
             strcat(LEARNFINAL, LEARN);// append/concatenate LEARN 7 times to LEARNFINAL
           }
             for (i = 0; i < sizeof(LEARNFINAL); i++)
             {  
               Send_Hex_Digit(DATA_PIN, LEARNFINAL[i], pulse);//send finished LEARNFINAL var
             }
             //PORTB &= ~(1 << DATA_PIN);//write low
         }
        break;
    case ALARMSEND:
         {
           state = ALARMTIMEOUT;//set state
           char ALARMFINAL[168];//make ALARMFINAL var and define length
           strcpy(ALARMFINAL, ALARM);//copy ALARM to new ALARMFINAL var
            for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
            {
               strcat(ALARMFINAL, ALARM);// append/concatenate ALARM 7 times to ALARMFINAL
            }
             for (i = 0; i < sizeof(ALARMFINAL); i++)
             {
               Send_Hex_Digit(DATA_PIN, ALARMFINAL[i], pulse);//send finished ALARMFINAL var
             }
             //PORTB &= ~(1 << DATA_PIN);//write low
         }
        break;
    case HEARTBEATSEND:
         {
             state = CHECKING;//change state
             char HEARTBEATPREFINAL[160];//make HEARTBEATPREFINAL var and define length
             strcpy(HEARTBEATPREFINAL, HEARTBEAT);//copy HEARTBEAT to new HEARTBEATPREFINAL var
              for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++)
              {
                 strcat(HEARTBEATPREFINAL, HEARTBEAT);// append/concatenate HEARTBEAT 7 times to HEARTBEATPREFINAL
              }
             for (i = 0; i < sizeof(HEARTBEATPREFINAL); i++)
             {
               Send_Hex_Digit(DATA_PIN, HEARTBEATPREFINAL[i], pulse);//send finished HEARTBEATPREFINAL var
             }
         }
        break;
    case HEARTBEATTIMEOUT:
             state = CHECKING;//change state
             if ((Mill - Delay_Start_Heartbeat) >= DELAY_TIME_ZONE_HEARTBEAT)
             {
                 Delay_Start_Heartbeat += DELAY_TIME_ZONE_HEARTBEAT;//prevents drift
                 state = HEARTBEATSEND;//change state when time ends
             }
        break;
    case ALARMTIMEOUT:
             state = ALARMTIMEOUT;//change state
             if ((Mill - Delay_Start_Check_Alarm) >= DELAY_TIME_CHECKALARM_TIMEOUT)
             {
                 state = CHECKING;//change state when time ends
             } 
        break;
    case LEARNTIMEOUT:
             state = LEARNTIMEOUT;//change state
             if ((Mill - Delay_Start_Learn) >= DELAY_TIME_CHECKLEARN_TIMEOUT)
             {
                 state = CHECKING;//change state when time ends
             } 
        break;
    default:
        //do nothing
        break;
    }
}

void Send_Hex_Digit(uint8_t pin, char c, uint16_t pulse) 
{
  byte bc = c - 48 ; // convert c to number 0 to 15
  for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    bitWrite(PORTB, pin, bitRead(bc, i));
    delayMicroseconds(pulse);
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  Check_Alarm_And_Heartbeat();
}
```

Comment: So after the alarm trigger you want 7s timeout, before the code checks the trigger again? In that case I would expect, that you set `Delay_Start_Check_Alarm` if the alarm was triggered, but I cannot see such a line. You are setting it in setup and then only incrementing it in the timeout. It is never actually set to the alarm trigger timestamp.

Comment: Have you got compiler warnings switched on? You are declaring a variable within a case `unsigned char HEARTBEATPREFINAL[160]` without wrapping the case code in `{ }` to make a block.

Comment: In `case CHECKING:` you have not considered the combination `if((alarmState) && (learnState))` . Even if that should  never happen maybe it should be handled?

Comment: @chrisl Thanks for the suggestion! I should only need it to be set in the timeout as the 
 `ALARMTIMEOUT` switch will loop over itself until the 7s are up, but I'll take a closer look when neatening up

Comment: @6v6gt Yes compiler warnings were off. I knew something was amiss there. I have implementing your suggestions but sadly the occasional runaway burst is still happening. I may have to just use a blocking `delay()` but would rather not. Will continue to think about it...

Comment: @chrisl I Thought about it some more and think I see what you mean. Testing it now shows much better results will see over time.  I added `Delay_Start_Check_Alarm = Mill;` to update the time before the timeout.

Comment: What incidentally have you connected to pins 3 and 4 ? You have the pullup resistors active but appear to be using positive logic `uint8_t alarmState = PINB&8;//read alarm pin 3` then go on to do a test like `if((alarmState) . . .`. I'd have expected something like this: `bool alarmState = !(PINB&8);//read alarm pin 3` since the "normal" (untriggered) state with the pull-up is HIGH. If the devices connected to pins 3 and 4 have a push-pull output then you should not use the built in pull up resistors.

Comment: @6v6gt Just the transistor of a PIR alarm terminals,  sensor open to GND when not triggered, goes to  5v with internal pullup when triggered. I will probably switch to the ATTINY412 once my order arrives and then modify the sketch using accordingly. So far with the sketch in current state it's been running well. I just periodically test it by pulling the pins 3 & 4 to GND. I'm hoping to test the reliability/timer for 2 months then will do the same for the ATTINY412

Comment: The main issue seems to have been the absence of the `Delay_Start_Check_Alarm = Mill;//keep time` before the timeout loop as @chrisl commented. with the time now kept the unwanted TX at the start seems to have disappeared but will test more to 100% confirm.

Comment: If the main problem appears to have been solved, i.e. you can't easily repeat it. then I guess you can write the answer yourself to close the issue, summarizing what you have done and acknowledge the contribution of @chrisl who seams to have identified a significant logic problem in your code. Or maybe wait 24 hours to give chrisl the opportunity to write an answer and get a few brownie points for it.

Comment: Sure thing, will wait a while then close.

Comment: You could also reduce this function to about 10 lines of code:
`void Send_Hex_Digit(uint8_t pin, char c, uint16_t pulse) {
  byte bc = c - 48 ; // convert c to number 0 to 15
  bitWrite( PORTB, pin , bitRead( bc, 3 ) ;
  delayMicroseconds(pulse) ;
  bitWrite( PORTB, pin , bitRead( bc, 2 ) ;
  delayMicroseconds(pulse) ;
  bitWrite( PORTB, pin , bitRead( bc, 1 ) ;
  delayMicroseconds(pulse) ;
  bitWrite( PORTB, pin , bitRead( bc, 0 ) ;
  delayMicroseconds(pulse) ;
}`   (not beautifully formatted here)

Comment: I don't see any over-current protection. A battery like that may be able to deliver over 50amps to your project for long enough to turn it into a suboptimal user experience. Even just being attended, screwing around with this on a table, it would be better to have an inline fuse holder or something.

Comment: @6v6gt Awesome removed 4% off of the program storage space in my sketch.

Comment: @timemage I have some room on the protoboard for additional circuitry so will definitely give it a go .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After implementing the suggestions I was able to make the sketch smaller and also solve the unwanted transmitting for the 2 timeouts (`pin3`, `pin4`).

The main issue was a 7s timeout before the sketch checks the High/Low.

This was solved by setting `Delay_Start_Check_Alarm` and `Delay_Start_Learn` in my switch statement, if the alarm was triggered.

```
    Delay_Start_Check_Alarm = Mill;//Setting this solved the issue
```

The heartbeat did not need this change since it gets set every time `HEARTBEATTIMEOUT` is called so it works ok.

The code in the question is also updated.

Big thanks to *@chrisl*, *@6v6gt* and *@timemage*.

Comment: `void Send_Hex_Digit()` could be even smaller with a `for loop` but the law of diminishing returns soon cuts in.

Comment: @6v6gt Added the for loop made it 1% smaller but still looks good and the ATiny412 sketch will also be happy

Comment: `for (uint8_t i = 4; i > 0; i--)` check that loop carefully. I thought `i` had values from 3 down to 0. But be very careful of using an an unsigned integer as a decrementing loop index. For example `for (uint8_t i = 3; i >= 0; i--)` gives an infinite loop.

Comment: @6v6gt changed back to int so it should work correctly. `for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)`Will do some more tests as well